# Dired Mode : View file

Tags: emacs, dired

I am running following sequence.

1. Open  dired mode with C-x d and  select a directory.
2. View a file in that directory with 'v'.
3. Kill that file with C-x k RET.

I see that  Current buffer is  one of the previously opened (P)  something else rather than the one in dired mode.  Even if I kill this  buffer P with C-x k RET
I still do not see the dired-mode buffer.

I like to go back to the dired-mode buffer.  I can still get it via C-x C-b, but I would prefer that this should be automatic choice once I view the file and kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `q` for `View-quit` (or `Q` for `View-quit-all`). That's important, because those to actually try to restore the windows configuration.

If you can't restrain your muscle memory you can bind `C-x k` to `View-quit`

```
(add-hook 'view-mode-hook (lamdba () (local-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'View-quit))
```

Comment: That is not sufficient. I also use 'RET' instead of 'v' and I am looking for returning back to dired buffer when I kill the file-buffer.

Comment: Then you have to look for conflicts. The behavior you describe is not the default one. After a kill the previous buffer is restored, i.e. the one you get with `C-x <left>`.

Comment: Exactly, where and how I should look for conflicts?

Comment: That depends on your config. First try it on a clean Emacs `emacs -Q` then load your config chunk-wise until you can reproduce. My bet is on packages that deal with buffers.